# Search a MySQL database using blob data?

Tags: c#, mysql, search, blob

Is it possible to search through a MySQL database using blob data to find close matches with other blob data types?

I have created my database with images stored as blob. I was wondering if it was possible to take a picture similar to the one in the database, convert it to blob as well and use it to search the database to find the similar picture already there?  My money is on no, but I thought I would just ask it anyways.  And if it isn't possible would you mind giving a hint as to what I need to do in order to accomplish a task along the same lines as my question?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not. MySQL has no idea what the bytes in your `BLOB` column mean -- it doesn't even know that they're images, let alone how to decode them and compare them for similarity. That's a far more complex computer vision task.

Comment: I thought as much, thanks for your input though!  Now just to figure out how to accomplish something else to compare them somehow..